# Incoming GET /patients Request from User-Agent PostmanRuntime/7.29.2 Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 'localhost',

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I'm trying to  build an API using Nodejs, express, Typescript & MySql DataBase. But i'm getting below error when I try to connect to MySql. After going through couple of articles on stack overflow and other sites, I have changed the HostName from localhost to 127.0.0.1 even that didn't help in resolving the issue.

**Error**

```
Incoming GET /patients Request from User-Agent PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND '127.0.0.1',
    at PromisePool.query (D:\Thota\TypeScript_Course\API\nodejsapi\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:341:22)
    at D:\Thota\TypeScript_Course\API\nodejsapi\src\controller\patient.controller.ts:19:45
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (D:\Thota\TypeScript_Course\API\nodejsapi\src\controller\patient.controller.ts:5:58)    
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: -3008,
  sql: undefined,
  sqlState: undefined,
  sqlMessage: undefined
}
```

**Error with Hostname is localhost**

```
[nodemon] starting `ts-node src/index.ts`   
 Application is Running on :  192.168.56.1:5000
[20/11/2022, 13:20:15] Incoming GET /patients Request from User-Agent PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 'localhost',
    at PromisePool.query (D:\Thota\TypeScript_Course\API\nodejsapi\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:341:22)
    at D:\Thota\TypeScript_Course\API\nodejsapi\src\controller\patient.controller.ts:19:45
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (D:\Thota\TypeScript_Course\API\nodejsapi\src\controller\patient.controller.ts:5:58)    
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: -3008,
  sql: undefined,
  sqlState: undefined,
  sqlMessage: undefined
}
```

**Code**

**Env file**

```
DB_HOST='127.0.0.1',
DB_USER='patientsdb',
DB_PASSWORD='patientsdb',
DB_NAME='patientdb',
DB_CONNECTION_LIMIT=10,
SERVER_PORT=5000
```

**mySqlconfig.ts**

```
import { createPool } from "mysql2/promise";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();


export const connection =async () => {
    const pool = await createPool({
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        port: 3306|| process.env.DB_PORT,
        connectionLimit : 10 || process.env.DB_CONNECTION_LIMIT
    });
    
    return pool;
}
```

**controller.ts**

```
import { Request, Response } from "express"
import { FieldPacket, OkPacket, ResultSetHeader, RowDataPacket } from "mysql2";
import { connection } from "../config/mysql.config";
import { HttpResponse } from "../domain/response";
import { Code } from "../enum/code.enum";
import { Status } from "../enum/status.enum";
import { patients } from "../interface/patients";
import { QUERY } from "../query/patient.query";

type ResultSet = [RowDataPacket[] | RowDataPacket[][] | OkPacket | OkPacket[] | ResultSetHeader, FieldPacket[]]



export const getPatients = async(req:Request, res:Response):Promise<Response<patients[]>> =>{
    console.info(`[${new Date().toLocaleString()}] Incoming ${req.method} ${req.originalUrl} Request from ${req.rawHeaders[0]} ${req.rawHeaders[1]}`);
    try{
        const pool = await connection();
        const result:ResultSet = await pool.query(QUERY.SELECT_PATIENTS);
        return res.status(Code.OK)
                  .send(new HttpResponse(Code.OK,Status.OK, 'Patient Retrived' , result[0]));
    } catch(error:unknown){
            console.error(error) 
        return res.status(Code.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
               .send(new HttpResponse(Code.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, 'An Error Occurred '));
    }
};

export const getPatient = async(req:Request, res:Response):Promise<Response<patients>> =>{
    console.info(`[${new Date().toLocaleString()}] Incoming ${req.method} ${req.originalUrl} Request from ${req.rawHeaders[0]} ${req.rawHeaders[1]}`);
    try{
        const pool = await connection();
        const result:ResultSet = await pool.query(QUERY.SELECT_PATIENT , [req.params.patientId]);
        if((result[0] as Array<ResultSet>).length>0){
            return res.status(Code.OK)
            .send(new HttpResponse(Code.OK,Status.OK, 'Patient Retrived' , result[0]));
        }else{
            return res.status(Code.NOT_FOUND)
                   .send(new HttpResponse(Code.NOT_FOUND,Status.NOT_FOUND, 'Patient NOT Found'));
        }

    } catch(error:unknown){
        console.error(error)
        return res.status(Code.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
               .send(new HttpResponse(Code.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, 'An Error Occurred '));
    }
};

export const createPatient = async(req:Request, res:Response):Promise<Response<patients>> =>{
    console.info(`[${new Date().toLocaleString()}] Incoming ${req.method} ${req.originalUrl} Request from ${req.rawHeaders[0]} ${req.rawHeaders[1]}`);
    let Patient:patients = {...req.body}
    try{
        const pool = await connection();
        const result:ResultSet = await pool.query(QUERY.CREATE_PATIENT , Object.values(Patient));
        Patient ={ id : (result[0] as ResultSetHeader).insertId,...req.body}        
            return res.status(Code.CREATED)
            .send(new HttpResponse(Code.CREATED,Status.CREATED, 'Patient Created' , Patient));
        }

     catch(error:unknown){
        console.error(error)
        return res.status(Code.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
               .send(new HttpResponse(Code.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, 'An Error Occurred '));
    }
};

export const updatePatient = async(req:Request, res:Response):Promise<Response<patients>> =>{
    console.info(`[${new Date().toLocaleString()}] Incoming ${req.method} ${req.originalUrl} Request from ${req.rawHeaders[0]} ${req.rawHeaders[1]}`);
    let Patient:patients = {...req.body}
    try{
        const pool = await connection();
        const result:ResultSet = await pool.query(QUERY.SELECT_PATIENT , [req.params.patientId]);
        if((result[0] as Array<ResultSet>).length>0){
            const result:ResultSet = await pool.query(QUERY.UPDATE_PATIENT , [...Object.values(Patient),req.params.patientId]);
            return res.status(Code.OK)
            .send(new HttpResponse(Code.OK,Status.OK, 'Patient Updated' , {...Patient,id:req.params.patientId}));
        }else{
            return res.status(Code.NOT_FOUND)
                   .send(new HttpResponse(Code.NOT_FOUND,Status.NOT_FOUND, 'Patient NOT Found'));
        }

    } catch(error:unknown){
        console.error(error)
        return res.status(Code.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
               .send(new HttpResponse(Code.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, 'An Error Occurred '));
    }
};

export const deletePatient = async(req:Request, res:Response):Promise<Response<patients>> =>{
    console.info(`[${new Date().toLocaleString()}] Incoming ${req.method} ${req.originalUrl} Request from ${req.rawHeaders[0]} ${req.rawHeaders[1]}`);
   
    try{
        const pool = await connection();
        const result:ResultSet = await pool.query(QUERY.SELECT_PATIENT , [req.params.patientId]);
        if((result[0] as Array<ResultSet>).length>0){
            const result:ResultSet = await pool.query(QUERY.DELETE_PATIENT , [req.params.patientId]);
            return res.status(Code.OK)
            .send(new HttpResponse(Code.OK,Status.OK, 'Patient Deleted' ));
        }else{
            return res.status(Code.NOT_FOUND)
                   .send(new HttpResponse(Code.NOT_FOUND,Status.NOT_FOUND, 'Patient NOT Found'));
        }

    } catch(error:unknown){
        console.error(error)
        return res.status(Code.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
               .send(new HttpResponse(Code.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, 'An Error Occurred '));
    }
};
```

**PatientQuery.ts**

```
export const QUERY =  {
    SELECT_PATIENTS : 'SELECT * FROM patients ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 50',
    SELECT_PATIENT : 'SELECT * FROM patients WHERE id = ?',
    CREATE_PATIENT : 'INSERT INTO patients (first_name,last_name,email, address,diagnosis,phone,status,image_url) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
    UPDATE_PATIENT : 'UPDATE patients set first_name = ?, last_name = ? ,email = ?, address = ?,diagnosis = ?,phone = ?,status = ?,image_url = ? WHERE id= ?',
    DELETE_PATIENT : 'DELETE FROM patients WHERE id= ?'
}
```

**App.ts**

```
import cors from "cors";
import express, { Application, Request, Response } from "express";
import ip from "ip";
import { HttpResponse } from "../src/domain/response";
import { Code } from "./enum/code.enum";
import { Status } from "./enum/status.enum";
import patientRoutes from "./routes/patient.routes";

export class APP {
    private readonly app:Application;
    private readonly APPLICATION_RUNNING = " Application is Running on : ";
    private readonly ROUTE_NOT_FOUND = "Application Route Not Found";

    constructor(private readonly port:(string | number) = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3000){
        this.app = express();
        this.middleware();
        this.route();
    }
    
    listen() : void {
        this.app.listen(this.port);
        console.info(`${this.APPLICATION_RUNNING} ${ip.address()}:${this.port}`);

    }

    private middleware() : void{
        this.app.use(cors({origin: '*'}));
        this.app.use(express.json());
    }

    private route():void {
        this.app.use('/patients',patientRoutes);
        this.app.get('/',(req: Request,res: Response ) =>res.status(Code.OK).send(new HttpResponse(Code.OK, Status.OK, 'Welcome to Patients API v1.0')));
        this.app.all('*',(req:Request, res: Response) =>res.status(Code.NOT_FOUND).send(new HttpResponse(Code.NOT_FOUND,Status.NOT_FOUND, this.ROUTE_NOT_FOUND)));
    }
    

}
```

**PatientRoute.ts**

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { createPatient, deletePatient, getPatient, getPatients, updatePatient } from "../controller/patient.controller";

const patientRoutes = Router();

patientRoutes.route('/')
    .get(getPatients)
    .post(createPatient);

patientRoutes.route('/:patientId')
    .get(getPatient)
    .put(updatePatient)
    .delete(deletePatient);


export default patientRoutes;
```

I feel error seem to be misleading as I'm able to successfully connect to MySqlDB using below script. Can someone advise what could be the error.

```
async function main (){
  const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");

  const connection = await mysql.createConnection({host: 'localhost', user: 'patientsdb',password: 'patientsdb',database: 'patientdb'});

  const  [rows, fields]= await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM `patients`');

  console.log(connection)

  console.log(rows)
}

main();
```

**output**

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    first_name: 'kiran',
    last_name: 'thota',
    email: 'abc@abc',
    address: 'london',
    diagnosis: 'bab',
    phone: '121212',
    status: 'discharged',
    created_at: 2022-11-20T00:36:05.000Z,
    image_url: 'www.google.com'
  }
]
```

[enter image description here][1]

**screentshot with output**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwjvu.png

Comment: #1 Validate the mysql connection with some tool like sql developer, phpmyadmin, pure shell client, sqlyog, etc. #2 What is your os?  #3 Share a GitHub client to test it :)

Comment: Hi @JRichardsz, #1 I have validated the connection Deaver , workbench and I'm able to connect to the Database. #2 My OS is windows, #3 please below gitgub link https://github.com/kirankthota79/NodejsApi/tree/main/src

Comment: I will review your code, in the mid-time compare your code with this https://github.com/no-more-it-depends/simple-mysql-crud-without-database-frameworks/tree/main/nodejs

Comment: your log states that "Application is Running on :  192.168.56.1:5000" try this ip and port in the browser

Comment: @Aditya_Anand I'm using same ip and port which is showing in logs.

Comment: It says that error is generated from the line "patient.controller.ts:19:45" which is your res.send . Can you check if you have a webserver reverse proxying and it is configured properly or not? because it is trying to return the response to localhost

Comment: Thanks all for the help on this, I have found the issue and resolved it. the issue was with environment variables, I was using comma after variable name it worked after removing the comma.                                                                                                 Env variables after correcting                                                                                                 DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=patient
DB_PASSWORD=patient
DB_NAME=patientsdb
DB_CONNECTION_LIMIT=10
SERVER_PORT=5000